# How to make ggplot legend add objects horizontally (vs vertically)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

The legend in `ggplot` can be moved to the *bottom* of the graphic as a *horizontal* legend by adding the following arguments to the `theme` function:

- `legend.position="bottom"` moves the legend below the graph
- `legend.direction="horizontal"` orients the legend to be horizontal.

However, not really...

The `legend.direction="horizontal"` simply seems to decrease the number of rows in the legend and the number of legend objects *in* each row.

This can be done manually using `guides(color=guide_legend(nrow=x)`

```
dat <- data.frame(plot = rep(letters,2), val = rep(1:length(letters),2))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = val, color = plot)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(nrow=2))
```

[image]

**Regardless**....

If you notice in the graphic output of the above code, even though I can control the "dimensions" of my legend (i.e., the number of rows), **I can't figure out how to change the *ordering* of the legend from vertical to horizontal**.

- So instead of `a` being *above* `b` etc. ("*vertically*" sorted) as above, I want `b` to be added *next to* `a` ("`horizontally`" sorted).

**How do I make my legend add objects *horizontally* vs vertically?**

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `byrow = TRUE` to `guide_legend`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = val, color = plot)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(nrow=2, byrow = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: I swear you can look all day and miss the one simple answer you need! Thanks, @joran. +1